# cardview on click returns wrong result

Tags: android, onclick, android-cardview, cardview

I have a few CardView items. I want to open different activity when I click on it.
This is part of my CardView adapter class

```
 @Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return productGroups.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    private TextView txtGroupName;
    public ViewHolder(final View view) {
        super(view);

        txtGroupName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtNameOfGroup);

        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (getLayoutPosition()){
                    case 0: Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(),MyProductsActivity.class);
                        view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                    case 1: Intent intent1 = new Intent(view.getContext(), VegetablesActivity.class);
                        view.getContext().startActivity(intent1);
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

I click on first item (want to open `MyProductsActivity.class`) but opens `VegetablesActivity.class`, and only when I click back button on my phone opens `MyProductsActivity.class`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to put a break:

```
        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (getLayoutPosition()){
                    case 0: Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(),MyProductsActivity.class);
                        view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                    break;                                            //Here
                    case 1: Intent intent1 = new Intent(view.getContext(), VegetablesActivity.class);
                        view.getContext().startActivity(intent1);
                    break;                                            //Here
                }

            }
        });
```